# Getting error #No module named 'obspy.clients.arclink' in the code for downloading earthquake data

Tags: error-handling, module

I am trying to download earthquake data and using Obspy and Obspy DMT for the same. I have setup anaconda to work with VS code on Linux. I have created the base anaconda and a separate environment for ob spy. After running the program for earthquake data download, I am getting the error #No module named 'obspy.clients.arclink'. I am new to computational seismology and python in general. Please excuse for any mistakes.
This is the error showing:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'obspy.clients.arclink'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

obspyDMT works with an older obspy version, you can downgrade via:

```
pip install obspy==1.2.2
```